# How to remove unity-greeter with all additional packages?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, uninstall

I'm using Xubuntu, I installed unity-greeter package via `sudo apt-get install unity-greeter`, it also installed A LOT OF other packages (ex I noticed 'Online accounts' in Settings). Then I removed it with `sudo apt-get remove unity-greeter` but it removed only `unity-greeter` package. My question is, how do i remove all the crap installed along with `unity-greeter` package? `sudo apt-get autoremove` doesn't find anything to remove.

Answer (score 2):

you could do with

```
sudo apt-get remove unity*
```

that will remove all the packages that are belongs to unity. you said you have Xubuntu installed , so you no need to worry to execute that command because there is nothing harm to your system . it will remove only unity.

Comment: okay, it removed "something" but i'm not sure if it's all. I still have "online accounts" in settings but i guess it can be only entry in come configuration file, right?

Comment: I think there is nothing you can do with that , because that from Ubuntu.

Comment: wouldn't be better if you use `autoremove` too?

Comment: we can autoremove too @Braiam my dear friend, :) but i reduced it to one single command.

Answer (score 1):

Try with  `sudo apt-get purge unity*` .
That should remove any leftover configuration files for Unity packages...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the online accounts seperately, look in synaptic for online accounts and remove it there.

Better question still is how to install unity-greeter without installing all the extra crap that comes with it, I mean it seriously does NOT need unity to be installed to use the greeter, it even installs rhythmbox ffs!